# How to stop pushing a UIViewController on top of itself?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, pushviewcontroller

Using the following simple layout.  I have a UINavigation Controller, with a root View Controller.  From the root view controller I have two other View Controller's that can be pushed from the Root View Controller.  My app has the ability to push a certain via controller, when it's close to an iBeacon.  While the iBeacon is irrelevant, the problem I'm having is sometimes the same View Controller will be push when it's already showing, causing a crash.

How can I prevent this?  I want to make sure if a certain View Controller is already pushed don't push it again, however, if another View Controller needs to be pushed, pop the one that isn't the root view controller, and push that one.

Error Message:

```
2014-02-27 11:16:08.038 Gimbal Proximity[3397:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3028ee83 0x3a5eb6c7 0x3028edc5 0x32a1ea67 0x32a1e9f3 0x32be74f9 0x32a24cf5 0x32be6d4d 0x32ba43e9 0x32ac1a17 0x32ac1821 0x32ac17b9 0x32a13353 0x32699943 0x32695167 0x32694ff9 0x32694a0d 0x3269481f 0x3268e54d 0x30259f69 0x302578f7 0x30257c43 0x301c2471 0x301c2253 0x34efc2eb 0x32a77845 0xe7489 0x3aae4ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Beacon 1 is the Root View Controller.

[image]

Here is the code to push the View Controllers from my root view controller.

```
NSArray* views = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSLog(@"views %@", views);

if ([visit.transmitter.name isEqualToString:@"Beacon1"])
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to Beacon 1");
    NSLog(@"Beacon 1 %@", self.navigationController.topViewController);

    [self showLabels];
    [self BeaconOne:@"10"];

}
else if ([visit.transmitter.name isEqualToString:@"Beacon2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to Beacon 2");


    ProductViewController *product_VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductViewController"];
    product_VC.productNumber  = @"0234609";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:product_VC animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Beacon 2 %@", self.navigationController.topViewController);
}
else if ([visit.transmitter.name isEqualToString:@"Beacon3"])
{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to Beacon 3");


    CurrentPromotionsViewController *currentPromotions_VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CurrentPromotionsViewController"];
    currentPromotions_VC.storeNumber          = 10;
    currentPromotions_VC.productCountryOrigin = @"France";
    currentPromotions_VC.productCategory      = @"Wine";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:currentPromotions_VC animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Beacon 3 %@", self.navigationController.topViewController);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting some notifications in your view controller and have it notify your root controller. For instance, when it loads, send back a notification that it's loaded, which sets a flag (`isShowing = YES` or something like that) and if that flag is set, don't push that controller again. Can send back another notification when the controller is popped to deactivate the flag.